# Data table old table data not clear after new search. Both old and new search table data showing in table

Tags: laravel

I am facing problem of Laravel Data Table search data . While searching data table first time , data in table showing correctly but when i select new selection for search, new data shown below the old table data... Check attached image, Image 1 - Showing first Search for id and having 4 entries after new search selection Image -2 showing 7 entries ( 4 for old search and 3 for new Search )

```
Ajax $('#selectid').on('change', function() {
var bidformilkrecord = $('#selectid').val(); 

                    $.ajax({  

                    url         :   '/getmilkrecordforbid', 
                    dataType    :   "json",
                    method      :   "POST",
                    data        :   {'bidformilkrecord': bidformilkrecord, "_token":"{{ 
                                    csrf_token()}}"},

                        success: function(data){ 
                            
                            //console.log(data)
                            //console.log(data.length)

                            var table = $('#milksummery').DataTable();

                            table.destroy();                    
                                
                            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                                
                                var row = $('<tr> <td>' + data[i].date+ '</td> <td>' + 
                                data[i].milkmorning + '</td> <td>' + data[i].milkevening + 
                                '</td> <td>' + data[i].totalmilk + '</td> </tr>');
                                $('#milksummery').append(row);
                                
                            }
                                var table = $('#milksummery').DataTable(); 

                        }, 

                    });

            });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: instead of destroy you can use `table.ajax.reload()` which will send an ajax request and update the table data with new data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older version of  DataTable try using following

`table.fnDestroy();`

instead of destroy()

Or you can try solution from here
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/44956/how-to-destroy-and-reinitialize-the-datatable

User sooli86  has mentioned this solution

```
// clear first
if(tableObj!=null){
tableObj.clear();
tableObj.destroy();
}

//2nd empty html
$(tableId + " tbody").empty();
$(tableId + " thead").empty();

//3rd reCreate Datatable object
tableObj= $(tableId).DataTable({
...
});
```